# What is the difference between extension property and extensionAttribute

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

i am trying to apply custom value to user in Microsoft graph.
should I use extension property or extension attribute which comes with on premise data sync

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/extensionproperty

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/onpremisesextensionattributes

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use `ExtensionProperty` because you can create custom extension property via Graph API.

`onPremisesExtensionAttributes` are predefined and I can imagine that more apps will use the same attribute and override it each other.

The extension attributes are neither selectable nor filterable. For an onPremisesSyncEnabled user, this set of properties is mastered on-premises and is read-only.

Comment: hmmm i see this info on extension property, what does this mean Azure AD schema extensions described here are available in Microsoft Graph for backwards compatibility reasons only. It allows you to use Microsoft Graph to continue to manage extension properties added through Azure AD Graph or Azure AD Connect. For new custom extensions, we recommend that you use Microsoft Graph schema extensions for adding custom data to resources.